# Accessory mode in Samsung Galaxy s3

Tags: android

am a noob in android environment, need to debug my application in accessory mode. My doubts are as follows:

1]How can i set my android device to accessory mode.
2]How can i debug my application using accessory mode.

Apologies in advance if my question is not upto the mark. Correct me if am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1] Once the device is detected the accessory asks the device to switch to accessory mode by sending a series of control transactions to the device. That is, you only need to configure your app to listen when the accessory was attached and interact with it ([See USB Accessory documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html)).

2] When debugging applications that use USB accessory or host features, you most likely will have USB hardware connected to your Android-powered device. To enable adb over wifi connection:

1. Connect the Android-powered device via USB to your computer.
2. From your SDK platform-tools/ directory, enter adb tcpip 5555 at the command prompt.
3. Enter adb connect :5555

You should now be connected to the Android-powered device and can issue the usual adb commands like adb logcat.

[image: example]